# Discount code system. comparing data entries to promote discount

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to establish a discount system within my already built system. What im trying to do is, compare values then if the discount code does or doesn't match i have columns in my database for different prices. if it does work use price list 2. if not price list 3 or 1. thanks in advance. p.s. im not very good with php

```
 $COTCode = $_SESSION['Price2'];

    if($COTCode == 'Y' || $DCode == 'Y'){

        $OverallTotal += $Price2 * $cartItem['quantity'];
        $_SESSION['SideCarriage'] += (($Price2 * $_SESSION['PostCalc2']) * $cartItem ['quantity']);

    }
    else if($_SESSION['PriceRate'] == 1){
            $OverallTotal += $Price1 * $cartItem['quantity'];
            $_SESSION['SideCarriage'] += (($Price1 * $_SESSION['PostCalc2']) * $cartItem['quantity']);
        }

        else {
            $OverallTotal += $Price3 * $cartItem['quantity'];
            $_SESSION['SideCarriage'] += (($Price3 * $_SESSION['PostCalc2']) * $cartItem['quantity']);
        }
```

obviously the code above works but i am not comparing input data to database data. ideally i want the price list to change on coupon check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would possibly take a different approach. Use a simple look up, remove a lot of the if structure you have where you would need to update the code when discount codes changes or expires, etc..

First handle the discount code:  Have a table that has a list of all the discount codes, type of discount code (percent, static amount off, etc..), the discount rate, valid dates the codes work, countries the codes work in, product ids the code is good for, etc..  You can expand this table later.

You can get a complex as using AJAX, JQuery, etc.. when updating the page dynamically, but basically I would start with:

1. Place a discount code in a special form field, after they have
   populated their cart and provided billing/shipping address
   information.
2. You query for the discount code, compare other
   criteria, and grab two values from the table:  discount type and
   discount amount.  Make sure to assign the discount type to a value
   that you can test on to know if the code was valid.
3. Perform the math, listing the amount of discount, and totals.
4. You should ONLY need to perform subtotals, totals, etc.. once.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you provide any additional information like database schema (if known)?  Provide any other blocks of code that might clarify where data is coming from?  Does this have to been down programmically or do you have some flexibility in how this is done?

Comment: basically i have a functions.php file which contains the above function. I only want the input to check the code if correct price list 3 is used. The other file cart2.php contains the form<tr>
  <td>Membership Code</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="thebox" size="22" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['incheck']; ?> tabindex="40" ;  /></td>
  <td>Check Code</td> 
  <td><input type="button" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Check']; ?> margin-left:"auto" margin-right:"auto" tabindex= "40" onkeypress="submit;" onclick="submit;" />
  </tr>

Comment: So far, you are only using session based values (form submitted values), there is no database query code.  You will need to add some code to the functions.php (create a new function or add it to the existing function) that opens a database connection, reads a value from a SQL statement, and close the connection.  Make sure you have the proper PHP extensions for mySQL and PHP data objects added.  Then refer to: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp for some sample code on creating a database connection.  Then add the query code: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: The only problem i have is how to to allocate a button click with the function code in functions..  specially as the form i have the inputbox and button in, is in a existing form..

Comment: in other words i cant work out how to, on submit change price list based on an input text because of it being in an existing form with an existing form action.

Comment: Let me see your code, maybe I can understand it while looking at it as a whole.  I will also run it by some colleagues. Please send me the relevant *.php files with functions, and the main php calling file.  Make sure to obliterate any hard-coded credentials or sensitive information.   Send them as attachments to:  upload.StackOv.rcxaocijjs@u.box.com.     This is a private UTBOX account folder.  I will purge the email address, folder and files once we are done.   Cheers!

Comment: I sent the email dude, of the three files i think most important

Comment: OK, received them, looking them over.  Taking this offline.  Please send email coming soon!

Comment: It looks like your question is beyond my rusty PHP.  Sorry I could not help further.